# jQuery on page load

Tags: jquery, hide, show, pageload

I have a script:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#projectReqTable","body").on({'click':function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("tr.main").nextUntil("tr.main").toggle("slow");
   }},
   "a.main",null);
});
</script>
```

What this do is it shows/hides rows on table. Now they are shown and I need to click on button to hide them. How do I hide then automatically on page load?

CSS property of hidden does the tricks, but I cannot filter afterwards the cells are shown. I need to hide them on page load ant the use the script to show them.

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to achieve. The display:none will make they start hidden and your jQuery will handle the rest...

Comment: That solution is not right for me because Table filter does not work afterwards. I need to hide them (simulate click) on page laod.
I should also add that I have not one button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function in jquery

You can Trigger the button click event on page load

```
$("#projectReqTable","body").trigger('click');
```

hope this helps

**More clearly**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#projectReqTable","body").on({'click':function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("tr.main").nextUntil("tr.main").toggle("slow");
   }},
   "a.main",null);


   $("#projectReqTable","body").trigger('click');

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I can't get it to work.
Tried the following:
$(function() {
  $("#projectReqTable","body").trigger('click');
});
<script>
(function(){
    $("#projectReqTable","body").trigger('click');
})();
</script>

Comment: Thank you for your help. But if I use your code (replacing with the script I use in first place), it seems that it does nothing.
I use this one : http://jsfiddle.net/wG8qf/7/ without tr.data {display:none;}​, because that way my filter filters empty rows.

Comment: Philemon philip Kunjumon, thank you. I found my problem. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Post your answer so that for those who are searching for this question again will be helpfull

Comment: I could solve your answer by giving just `$("#main-data-table").find('.data').css('display','none');`

Comment: I will post my answer after 8h (newbie here).

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to add `.click()` at the end. That simulates a click.

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#projectReqTable","body").on({'click':function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("tr.main").nextUntil("tr.main").toggle("slow");
   }},
   "a.main",null).click();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was simply to change filter column and bring him to tr.main column.

However, the solution that **Philemon philip Kunjumon** provided is very useful too.

Here is the full code if his solution:

```
$(function(){
  $("#main-data-table","body").on({'click':function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("tr.main").nextUntil("tr.main").toggle("fast");
   }},
   "a.main",null);
$("#main-data-table").find('.data').css('display','none');
});​
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/wG8qf/107/